# dygraphs - getting rid of black x and y axis for "sparkline"-style chart?

Tags: javascript, charts

I am new to the dygraphs library, and am trying to generate a "sparkline"-style chart that is very small, I can get the size and everything right, but I can't seem to get rid of the black x and y-axes.  Is there a way to set the color of the axes in dygraphs?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2):

Ben,

Check out:

http://dygraphs.com/tests/unboxed-spark.html for the full source of a working demo.

Here is the bit I think you are interested in.  You just need to set the drawXAxis and drawYAxis to false to make a sparkline style chart.  You just make them non-visible and don't have to worry about changing colors.

```
  var show_box = false;
  g = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("div_g"),
        data, {
          drawXAxis: show_box,
          drawYAxis: show_box,
          drawXGrid: show_box,
          drawYGrid: show_box
        }
      );
```